# Calculating depth mask from different lighting

Tags: computational-geometry, geometry, computer-vision

I have a object which is static, the camera is static and light source is moving. How can the depth mask be calculated ?

Concept is to use - calculate height from shadow length

[image]

Lets imagine a have more images likes this.

And light source is moving, which is *sun*, and from time it's position, distance, orientation can be calculated.

[image]

Yellow lines are sun rays.

Those circles are brightest pixel previously(direction of raw) of a very dark pixel. considering them highest i'n my knowledge . And those green lines as shadow. How can I calculated the depth mask of this terrain.

I'm ignoring the fact that, object/terrain can be colorful - no reflection/absorption.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/32565/4274, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/108881/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.